# Loop over a subset, source a file and save results in a dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, save, rdata

Similar questions have been asked already but none was able to solve my specific problem. I have a `.R` file ("Mycalculus.R") containing many basic calculus that I need to apply to subsets of a dataframe: one subset for each year where the modalities of "year" are factors (yearA, yearB, yearC) not numeric values. The file generates a new dataframe that I need to save in a Rda file. Here is what I expect the code to look like with a `for` loop (this one obviously do not work):

```
id <- identif(unlist(df$year))
for (i in 1:length(id)){
    data <- subset(df, year == id[i])
    source ("Mycalculus.R", echo=TRUE)
    save(content_df1,file="myresults.Rda")
}
```

Here is an exact of the main data.frame df:

```
obs    year    income    gender   ageclass    weight
 1     yearA    1000       F         1          10
 2     yearA    1200       M         2          25
 3     yearB    1400       M         2           5
 4     yearB    1350       M         1          11
```

Here is what the sourced file "Mycalculus.R" do: it applies numerous basic calculus to columns of the dataframe called "data", and creates two new dataframes df1 and then df2 based on df1. Here is an extract:

```
data <- data %>% 
   group_by(gender) %>% 
   mutate(Income_gender = weighted.mean(income, weight))
data <- data %>% 
   group_by(ageclass) %>% 
   mutate(Income_ageclass = weighted.mean(income, weight))

library(GiniWegNeg)
gini=c(Gini_RSV(data$Income_gender, weight), Gini_RSV(data$Income_ageclass,weight))

df1=data.frame(gini)
colnames(df1) <- c("Income_gender","Income_ageclass")
rownames(df1) <- c("content_df1")

df2=(1/5)*df1$Income_gender+df2$Income_ageclass
colnames(df2) <- c("myresult")
rownames(df2) <- c("content_df2")
```

So that in the end, I get two dataframes like this:

```
                    Income_Gender  Income_Ageclass    
content_df1           ....             ....
```

And for df2:

```
                    myresult      
content_df2           ....
```

But I need to save df1 and Rf2 as a Rda file where the row names of content_df1 and content_df2 are given per subset, something like this:

```
                    Income_Gender  Income_Ageclass    
content_df1_yearA     ....             ....     
content_df1_yearB     ....             ....     
content_df1_yearC     ....             ....
```

and

```
                    myresult
content_df2_yearA     ....   
content_df2_yearB     ....    
content_df2_yearC     ....
```

Currently, my program does not use any loop and is doing the job but messily. Basically the code is more than 2500 lines of code. (please don't throw  tomatoes at me).

Anyone could help me with this specific request?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply your question with a reproducible example. Provide two simple data.frames with yearA and yearB and do one simple function in your example Mycalculus.R file. This will make it easier for others to understand the nature of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider incorporating all in one script with a defined function of needed arguments, called by `lapply()`. Lapply then returns a list of dataframes that you can rowbind into one final df.

```
library(dplyr)
library(GiniWegNeg)

runIncomeCalc <- function(data, y){      
  data <- data %>% 
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    mutate(Income_gender = weighted.mean(income, weight))
  data <- data %>% 
    group_by(ageclass) %>% 
    mutate(Income_ageclass = weighted.mean(income, weight))      

  gini <- c(Gini_RSV(data$Income_gender, weight), Gini_RSV(data$Income_ageclass,weight))

  df1 <- data.frame(gini)
  colnames(df1) <- c("Income_gender","Income_ageclass")
  rownames(df1) <- c(paste0("content_df1_", y))

  return(df1)
}

runResultsCalc <- function(df, y){
  df2 <- (1/5) * df$Income_gender + df$Income_ageclass
  colnames(df2) <- c("myresult")
  rownames(df2) <- c(paste0("content_df2_", y)

  return(df2)
}

dfIncList <- lapply(unique(df$year), function(i) {      
  yeardata <- subset(df, year == i)
  runIncomeCalc(yeardata, i)      
})

dfResList <- lapply(unique(df$year), function(i) {      
  yeardata <- subset(df, year == i)
  df <- runIncomeCalc(yeardata, i) 
  runResultsCalc(df, i)      
})

df1 <- do.call(rbind, dfIncList)
df2 <- do.call(rbind, dfResList)
```

---

Now if you need to source across scripts. Create same two functions, *runIncomeCalc* and *runResultsCalc* in Mycalculus.R and then call each in other script:

```
library(dplyr)
library(GiniWegNeg)

if(!exists("runIncomeCalc", mode="function")) source("Mycalculus.R")

dfIncList <- lapply(unique(df$year), function(i) {      
  yeardata <- subset(df, year == i)
  runIncomeCalc(yeardata, i)      
})

dfResList <- lapply(unique(df$year), function(i) {      
  yeardata <- subset(df, year == i)
  df <- runIncomeCalc(yeardata, i) 
  runResultsCalc(df, i)      
})

df1 <- do.call(rbind, dfIncList)
df2 <- do.call(rbind, dfResList)
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly but only if my calculus generates one dataframe only (df1). It does not work anymore if my calculus generates a second dataframe (df2 based on df1). Here the code does not even generate the results for df1 anymore. I edited my question so that I am clearer on this point.

Comment: See update with same fct and args process. Simply add another function that receives df1 as input, then iterates with `lapply` to `rbind` at end. And source the two functions from other script.

Comment: In your update you wrote df in the runResultsCalc part instead of df1. It should be `df2 <- (1/5) * df1$Income_gender + df1$Income_ageclass` since df2 calculus is based on the results of df1. Was it on purpose and if not what is the impact of this on the rest of your presented code?

Comment: Not true as `df` is the function's local argument passed as parameter. In `dfResList` lapply(), its local `df` is the return of `runIncomeCalc()` which then passes its resultset to `runResultsCalc()`. Using `df1` would err out or return empty data as nowhere is it created in global environment except at very end. Of course test to confirm. Change names of repeated `df` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you functional-ize your steps you can create a workflow like the following:

```
calcFunc <- function(df) {
  ## Do something to the df, then return it
  df
}

processFunc <- function(fname) {
  ## Read in your table
  x <- read.table(fname)

  ## Do the calculation
  x <- calcFunc(x)

  ## Make a new file name (remember to change the file extension)
  new_fname <- sub("something", "else", fname)

  ## Write the .RData file
  save(x, file = new_fname)
}

### Your workflow
## Generate a vector of files
my_files <- list.files()

## Do the work
res <- lapply(my_files, processFunc)
```

Alternatively, don't save the files. Omit the `save` call in the `processFunc`, and return a list of data.frame objects. Then use either `data.table::rbindlist(res)` or `do.call(rbind, list)` to make one large data.frame object.

Comment: Given that my current .R calculus file (which I will have to funtional-ize as a first step) refers to the main data.frame in the calculus, I am afraid that the sub-setting will be override. I had this problem trying to use the `by` command. I was basically asking the program to "do something" by group but the "something" was referring to the main dataframe. It was therefore contradicting the `by group` instruction leading the program to run as many times as the number of subsets, but over the main dataframe. I am afraid of having the same issue here. What do you think?