# Forcing the use of a for loop with group_by and mutate()

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of data frames (generated by the permutation order of an initial dataframe) to which I would like to apply complicated calculus using `group_by_at()` and `mutate()`. It works well with a single data frame but fail using a `for` loop since `mutate` requires the name of the dataframe and some of my calculus as well. So I thought, well, let's create a list of different dataframes all having the same name and loop over the initial sequence of names. Unfortunately the trick does not work and I get the following message:

```
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.
```

Here is the self contained example showing all my steps. I think the problem comes from `mutate`. So, how could I force the use of `for loop` with `mutate`?

```
data <- read.table(text = 'obs  gender   ageclass    weight   year   subdata   income    
                        1     F         1         10     yearA     sub1   1000   
                        2     M         2         25     yearA     sub1   1200   
                        3     M         2          5     yearB     sub2   1400   
                        4     M         1         11     yearB     sub1   1350',
 header = TRUE)  


library(dplyr)
library(GiniWegNeg)

dataA <- select(data, gender, ageclass)
dataB <- select(data, -gender, -ageclass)
rm(data)

# Generate permutation of indexes based on the number of column in dataA
library(combinat)
index <- permn(ncol(dataA))

# Attach dataA to the previous list of index           
res <- lapply(index, function(x) dataA[x])

# name my list keeping track of permutation order in dataframe name
names(res) <- unlist(lapply(res,function(x) sprintf('data%s',paste0(toupper(substr(colnames(x),1,1)),collapse = ''))))

# Create a list containing the name of each data.frame name
NameList <- unlist(lapply(res,function(x) sprintf('data%s',paste0(toupper(substr(colnames(x),1,1)),collapse = ''))))

# Define as N the number of columns/permutation/dataframes
N <- length(res)

# Merge res and dataB for all permutation of dataframes
res <- lapply(res,function(x) cbind(x,dataB))

# Change the name of res so that all data frames are named data
names(res) <- rep("data", N)


# APPLY FOR LOOP TO ALL DATAFRAMES

for (j in NameList){

runCalc <- function(data, y){ 

  data <- data %>% 
    group_by_at(1) %>% 
    mutate(Income_1 = weighted.mean(income, weight))
  data <- data %>% 
    group_by_at(2) %>% 
    mutate(Income_2 = weighted.mean(income, weight))      

  gini <- c(Gini_RSV(data$Income_1, data$weight), Gini_RSV(data$Income_2,data$weight))

  Gini <- data.frame(gini)
  colnames(Gini) <- c("Income_1","Income_2")
  rownames(Gini) <- c(paste0("Gini_", y))

  return(Gini)
}

runOtherCalc <- function(df, y){
  Contrib <- (1/5) * df$Income_1 + df$Income_2
  Contrib <- data.frame(Contrib)
  colnames(Contrib) <- c("myresult")
  rownames(Contrib) <- c(paste0("Contrib_", y)

  return(Contrib)
}

# Run runCalc over dataframe data by year

df1_List <- lapply(unique(data$year), function(i) {      
  byperiod <- subset(data, year == i)
  runCalc(byperiod, i)      
})

# runCalc returns df which then passes to runOtherCalc, again by year

df1_OtherList <- lapply(unique(data$year), function(i)     
  byperiod <- subset(data, year == i)
  df <- runCalc(byperiod, i) 
  runOtherCalc(df, i)      
})

# Run runCalc over dataframe data by subdata

df2_List <- lapply(unique(data$subdata), function(i) {      
  byperiod <- subset(data, subdata == i)
  runCalc(bysubdata, i)      
})

# runCalc returns df which then passes to runOtherCalc, again by subdata

df2_OtherList <- lapply(unique(data$subdata), function(i)     
  bysubdata <- subset(data, subdata == i)
  df <- runCalc(bysubdata, i) 
  runOtherCalc(df, i)      
})


# Return all results in separate frames, then append by row in 2 frames

Gini_df1 <- do.call(rbind, df1_List)
Contrib_df1 <- do.call(rbind,df1_OtherList)
Gini_df2 <- do.call(rbind, df1_List)
Contrib_df2 <- do.call(rbind,df1_OtherList)

Gini <- rbind(Gini_df1, Gini_df2)
Contrib <- rbind(Contrib_df1, Contrib_df2)


}
```

Comment: The thing that you're missing in your dplyr pipe is `purrr::map`.

Can I suggest that you check out this video of Hadley explaining how to  solve exactly this problem while you wait for potential answers to be posted below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg 

Slide deck here: https://speakerdeck.com/hadley/managing-many-models

Comment: I did (and had a hard time with the cupcakes example). `purrr::map()` is a function for applying a function to each element of a list. I did not know this function. For my particular example I unfortunately don't exactly know how to compute it. As a newbie I have in mind `data <-map(datalist)` where `datalist` is my list of dataframes, but I do not understand how the results will be returned.

Comment: No where in your `for` loop do you use the *j* variable.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, the R error you receive below is a bit cryptic but usually it means you are running an operation on an object that does not exist.

> Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Specifically, it comes with your `lapply` call as *data* is not defined anywhere globally (only within the *runCalc* method) and as above you remove it with `rm(data)`.

```
dfList <- lapply(unique(data$year), function(i) {      
  byperiod <- subset(data, year == i)
  runCalc(byperiod, i)      
})
```

By, the way the use of `lapply...unique...subset` can be replaced with the underused grouping base R function, `by()`.

---

Gathering from your text and code, I believe you intend to run a *year* grouping on each dataframe of your list, *res*. Then consider two `by` calls, wrapped in a larger function that receives as a parameter a dataframe, *df*. Then run `lapply` across all items of list to return a new list of nested dataframe pairs.

```
# SECONDARY FUNCTIONS
runCalc <- function(data) {                                    
  data <- data %>% 
    group_by_at(1) %>% 
    mutate(Income_1 = weighted.mean(income, weight))
  data <- data %>% 
    group_by_at(2) %>% 
    mutate(Income_2 = weighted.mean(income, weight))      

  Gini <- data.frame(
              year = data$year[[1]],
              Income_1 = unname(Gini_RSV(data$Income_1, data$weight)), 
              Income_2 = unname(Gini_RSV(data$Income_2, data$weight)),
              row.names = paste0("Gini_", data$year[[1]])
          )

  return(Gini)
}

runOtherCalc <- function(df){
  Contrib <- data.frame(
                 myresult = (1/5) * df$Income_1 + df$Income_2,
                 row.names = paste0("Contrib_", df$year[[1]])
             )
  return(Contrib)
}

# PRIMARY FUNCTION
runDfOperations <- function(df) {   
  gList <- by(df, df$year, runCalc)     
  gTmp <- do.call(rbind, gList)

  cList <- by(gTmp, gTmp$year, runOtherCalc)
  cTmp <- do.call(rbind, cList)

  gtmp$year <- NULL
  return(list(gTmp, cTmp))
}

# RETURNS NESTED LIST OF TWO DFs FOR EACH ORIGINAL DF
new_res <- lapply(res, runDfOperations)

# SEPARATE LISTS IF NEEDED (EQUAL LENGTH)
Gini <- lapply(new_res, "[[", 1)
Contrib <- lapply(new_res, "[[", 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think a parenthesis is missing in `c(paste0("Gini_", data$year[[1]])`. The solution works but do not display Income_1 and Income_2 as colnames. Instead I get Gini_RSV and Gini_RSV.1 as colnames. Besides, I am stuck with another problem. In my attempt to present a self-contained example, I skipped some important part of the code, which is that dfList is not the only grouping. With this new line of code, I do not know which of the grouping as to be simplified and related to df. I edit my query so that this piece of code is added, the new grouping is `dfOtherList`.

Comment: I updated for first issue. For second, where does *subdata* derive? Does first two groupings relate? If not, we may need to produce a second list of dataframes with another `lapply` call.

Comment: I updated the code. _subdata_ is _year_ (my apology). _dfList_ applies the calculus _runCalc_ over _data_ by _year_, the results of which then passes to _runOtherCalc_ via function _dfOtherList_. See topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750824/loop-over-a-subset-source-a-file-and-save-results-in-a-dataframe/38754622?noredirect=1#comment64952215_38754622 for which you already helped 2 years ago.

Comment: Wow! Facepalm! How did I miss `by` back then! We live and learn. See update separating primary (calling `by` twice) and secondary functions, *runCalc* and *runOtherCalc*. Year must become a new column in *runCalc's* df return. Return is a nested list of df pairs that can be split at end.

Comment: Jesus, the cleaner the code is, the less applicable it is for my real worksheet... Is there a solution that does not require to create _year_ as a new column in _runCalc_'s df return? Your former (2 years ago) help which defined a function _i_ and equalize _year_ to _i_ indeed fitted better because in my real program, _year_ could be _year_ but could also be some other variables.

Comment: Say it differently, I would need _runCalc_ and _runOtherCalc_ to remain as it is in my example.

Comment: Simply drop year column after the second `by` and before `return` with `gtmp$year <- NULL`. See edit. Also, this code compared to previous answer only runs *runCalc* once. We avoid the duplicate run for *runOtherCalc*.

Comment: Still not working because it assumes I rely only on variable _year_, which is not the case. I edited the code by adding 2 extra lists _df2_List_ and _df2_OtherList_ (so that I now have 4 lists) which run the same functions _runCalc_ and _runOtherCalc_ based on `subdata`.